# How to generate index in angular

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive, angular7

How to add Serial number inside table tag

[image]

[image]

Comment: For incrementing it as i +1 , you need to write *ngFor=let st of stList; let i = index" or *ngFor=let st of stList; #i = index"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to access the index within the scope of `*ngFor` directive, so you should write it like below -

```
<tr *ngFor=let st of stList;let i = index">
<td>{{i+1}}</td>
/// other columns
</tr>
```

notice the `let` keyword , it restricts the scope of the variable within the `*ngFor` only.

Comment: @JohnMathew why you need to do that, infact the index exists only within the scope of *ngFor ,it's bad practice to initiate it from the typescript

Answer (score 1):

Possibly because it will be treated as a string. Maybe the best thing to do here is to do it in the component. Add another field to stList and call it RowCounter. Then populate this field and just print it to screen.

Something like...

```
let counter: number = 0;
this.stList.forEach((element: any) => {
 element.rowCount = counter+1;
};
```

****Further added in response to comment.****

Make it part of the Model stList. So add a property called rowCount to your StudentData model

Something like.

```
export interface StudentData {
 rowCount:number;
 name:string;
 gender: string;    
 age: number;
 address: Address;
 }
```

Then just reference it like your other properties

```
<tr>
    <td>{{st.rowCount}}</td>
    <td>{{st.name}}</td>
    --etc
</tr>
```

Arguably it is model data anyway.